# Ruby WeakRef has implicit race condition?

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection, race-condition

I'm looking at Ruby WeakRef, and it seems that the way the API is written has an implied race condition, though it seems very unlikely to hit.

The basic usage implied by the API is:

```
obj = Object.new
foo = WeakRef.new(obj)

# Later on:
if (foo.weakref_alive?)
    puts "I can allegedly use #{foo.to_s} now"
end

# Or even:
obj2 = foo.__getobj__ if foo.weakref_alive?
```

The problem lies in the fact that we don't have control over when garbage collection may happen, as an example, consider another thread running that regularly calls `GC.start`.

If we have garbage collection happening between the `weakref_alive?` check and the usage of the object, then we will end up hitting the `RefError` exception.

(I would actually expect that any large application that uses weakref - particularly those that are multithreaded - would hit RefErrors occasionally due to this)

I'm surprised there's no way to safely get the object in an atomic way if the object is available at the moment we check it.

So the question is first, am I overconcerned?  Is there some reason we don't have to *ever* worry about a GC happening if we fetch the object right away after checking it (as in the second example)?  And if not, then that gives us the second question, of the best way to safely work with weakrefs.

Right now I've added an 'obj' method to the class as one way to deal with it:

```
require 'weakref'
class WeakRef
  def obj
    begin
      return self.__getobj__
    rescue RefError
      return nil
    end
  end
end
```

But unnecessary 'rescue' statements kind of bug me.  I suppose we could also:

```
require 'weakref'
class WeakRef
  def obj
    savegc = GC.disable
    obj = self.weakref_alive? ? self.__getobj__ : nil
    GC.enable if savegc
    return obj
  end
end
```

But I'm skeptical that it's low-cost to just disable and re-enable the garbage collection, much less whether this is a completely atomic operation.

Any advice from ruby GC experts?

Comment: Seems highly unlikely (if at all possible) based on the circumstances described. Your call to `weakref_alive?` likely white marks this Object and thus it won't GC even if the GC is run immediately afterwards. [Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/MeagerGroundedSearch#main.rb)

Comment: @engineersmnky there are too many implementations, to consider a single example run in one particular implementation a proof. It requires a documentation that states explicitly that such a mark exists (and how long it persists). Being “unlikely” is not helpful for race conditions.

Comment: `WeakRef` uses an [`ObjectSpace::WeakMap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/ObjectSpace/WeakMap.html) internally to store the weak references. Although this class is intended for internal use (and thus may change in behavior between versions), I still found it more straight-forward to use it directly rather than via a `WeakRef`. Specifically, you can use `WeakMap#[]` to either get the still live object or `nil` if the referenced object was already garbage collected. `WeakRef#weakref_alive?`is effectively `!weak_map[key].nil?` for most objects.

Comment: @HolgerJust my mistake (previous comment removed). Additionally I fully support your recommendation as it explicitly provides the desired interface in the question

Comment: @engineersmnky - if you look at the fairly simply WeakRef code - it does no such "marking" - and in fact this would be impossible to do since it's impossible to know how long it needs to be whitelisted for.  Someone may just be checking weakref_alive? and not getting the object, and you wouldn't want to mark it indefinitely on the chance they may some day grab the object.

Comment: @HolgerJust I thought about using WeakMap, but the doc says:  "This class is mostly used internally by WeakRef, please use lib/weakref.rb for the public interface." - so I was trying to respect that, though maybe that was a mistake.

And are there really two Holgers commenting on this question?  :)

Comment: @DavidLjungMadisonStellar the marking (white, grey, black) is an extremely internal mechanism leveraged by the generational GC it would not be readily aparent in the source code for WeakRef. My example shows that if such marking occurs which I still surmise is likely, it would be extremely ephemeral.

Comment: @engineersmnky Case in point: I have implemented something using `WeakMap` recently. I found it impossible to reliably test this since I could not reliably ensure that the referenced out-of-scope object was actually garbage collected in the test-suit. Sometimes this was apparently delayed based on things such as memory pressure, number of GC runs, the exact Ruby version, or a thousand other things. Those things are by definition racey :)

Comment: @HolgerJust the race condition under discussion (atleast as I understand it) is that the delegated object could be GC'd between a reference check and immediate subsequent retrieval. This specific instance I do not believe to be possible or racey but yes using `WeakRef` objects is naturally difficult due to the circumstances you described.

Comment: @engineersmnky  - I think you are missing the two points I am making.  1)  I have looked at the WeakRef source and it does *not* do any marking.  2) I am claiming that it would be impossible to add any sort of marking to WeakRef that would both guarantee fixing the race condition I describe and still allow GC of WeakRef objects.  So marking does not and *can not* happen to fix this.

(framed another way: whatever marking you add to WeakRef, I guarantee I can create a race condition situation, however unlikely, unless you simply disallow GC of anything in WeakRef, which is now no longer weak)

Comment: @engineersmnky - here is the race condition more explicitly.  The code is basically "if 'weakref_alive?' then <use object>"

The problem is that after the weakref_alive? check, what if we switched to another thread, and that thread caused GC (either explicitly with GC.start) or ruby just decides to GC?  The object is now GC'd and no longer alive.  We try to reference it, and get a RefError.

Comment: @DavidLjungMadisonStellar I think your missing my point too and that's okay since I have not proven my point and you have not proven yours this is merely hypothetical. That being said as I mentioned the source for WeakRef will not show you the mark. Marking is a deeply internal mechanism of the GC itself you could look into ruby GC mark and sweep it is actually very interesting how it is implemented (although I'll admit some of it is over my head).

Comment: @engineersmnky - here is the proof.

if you access weakref_alive? it could, at best, mark the object as something to hold on to for a little longer. It cannot know when(or if!) you will actually then access the object, and any amount of concurrent code could get in between your check and access.  Consequently, as I mentioned above, if that code takes longer than the length of time it is waiting then, again, you can end up with a RefError.  If it marks it permanently, then that would mean that any weakref_alive? check would make the ref no longer weak, defeating the point.  There is my proof.

Comment: @engineersmnky - put more simply, the call to weakref_alive? does not (and *can not*) have the information it needs to mark the ref properly.  This problem is intractable as the API is written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, please note the intended use for a `WeakRef` object, namely to stand in for the original object. Here, the `WeakRef` object implements the full duck-typed interface of the referenced object by forwarding all messages sent to it. As such, the `WeakRef` object is intended to be used directly in place of the original object (if it is still available).

While you may get a reference to the original object (if it is still available) with `WeakRef#__getobj__`, this is intended to be a special use-case and more of an implementation detail of the message delegation. If you do this however, you can check if the referenced object is still available with `WeakRef#weakref_alive?`. As you have noticed, there is the (at least theoretical) option for a race-condition, depending on your used Ruby implementation.

To be sure that you handle such race-conditions gracefully, you can indeed rescue the `RefError` if it occurs. You can just optimize the non-race-condition case a bit:

```
obj = Object.new
foo = WeakRef.new(obj)

begin
  obj2 = foo.__getobj__ if foo.weakref_alive?
rescue RefError
   obj2 = nil
end
```

You can use the same pattern for any other message sent to your weak reference (which then gets forwarrdr to your referenced object), e.g.

```
begin
  foo.to_s if foo.weakref_alive?
rescue RefError
  # # do nothing as foo is a dangling reference to a garbage-collected object
end
```

Depending on your use-case, this may be a bit awkward though. Also, sometimes it is necessary to have the actual object reference rather than a wrapped object (which may behave differently when inquired about its specific class., e.g. in a `case` statement).

Here, an option could be to use `ObjectSpace::WeakMap` instead of the `WeakRef`. This class is used internally by `WeakRef` to actually hold the weak references. Ruby actually discourages the use of this class and regards it as an internal class. However, I found it to be useful to implement a more straight-forward lookup than with just `WeakRef`. Just be aware that the behavior in this area might subtly change and it might be a good idea to read changelogs as you update your Ruby versions.

With that out of the way, a sample lookup with `ObjectSpace::WeakMap` could look like this:

```
# The WeakMap object which can store multiple maps from an
# existing object to another (potentially garbage-collected) object.
# If you need multiple weak references, you can still use
# a single map.
WEAK_MAP = ObjectSpace::WeakMap.new

# Our referenced object which may or may not be garbage-collected later
obj = Object.new

# The "marker" object is the key in map. It is used to look the reference
# to the intended object. You need to always use the same object here
# (rather than e.g. a similar string) as the actual object_id of the marker
# is used for the lookup of the referenced object
marker = Object.new

# Store a reference in the weak map
WEAK_MAP[marker] = obj

#########################################################
# Now do something else...                              #
# obj may be garbage-collected in the meantime.         #
# You need to hold onto the marker object though!       #
#########################################################

# Now, you can retrieve a reference to the actual
# original object (if it is still available) or nil
# if obj was already garbage-collected
obj2 = WEAK_MAP[marker]
```

As written above, the `WeakRef` class uses exactly this mechanism internally. Here, the `WeakRef` object uses itself as the marker. That is, as long as you hold the actual `WeakRef` object. The simplified lookup in `WeakRef#__getobj__` thus looks like this:

```
class WeakRef
  WEAK_MAP = ObjectSpace::WeakMap.new

  def __getobj__
    WEAK_MAP[self] || raise RefError, "Invalid Reference"
  end

  def weakref_alive?
    !WEAK_MAP[self].nil?
    # actually, it's this mostly equivalent code
    # WEAK_MAP.key?(self)
  end
end
```

You can find the implementation of the WeakRef class at https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/lib/weakref.rb - have a look, it's actually quite readable.

Comment: Yup - perhaps the question is really, why doesn't WeakRef have a simple way to access the object (or nil) without raising an error, or else why is weakmap usage discouraged?  It kind of leaves us with no good option - either we use the discouraged class, or we have to dig into WeakRef's internal implentation.

I'll make a suggestion to the weakref implementer and point him towards all of this.

So I guess this qualifies as an answer, which really is just "yes, there is a race, and there's not really a good solution to it"

Comment: The general WeakRef API is quite old (it was already present in at least 1.8.6). However, the underlying implementation has changed significantly in Ruby 2.0 with the introduction of `WeakMap` as it was found to not be safe in Ruby 1.9. There was quite some discussion about the desired functionality and its API though. See https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4168. As for the possible race or generally the case that the referenced object is garbage collected, the basic accepted solution is to try to send a message and to handle a `RefError` exception if it occurs.

Comment: Yes - I know of the 1.9 GC issues.  I think the answer is that the API has an implicit race and, essentially, if you need to access the object then weakref_alive? is of no use to actually protect you.  It's worsened by the fact that there's an implied use that will actually break if the user isn't well-versed in concurrent code execution issues. It's a shame the API isn't fixed since it's incredibly simple to fix - and I've posted a request to the WeakRef maintainers.